# Preserving Home Made Pasta

Tags: pasta, food-preservation

How would one go about doing this?  Is it safe to freeze?

Answer (score 7):

Pasta freezes well if you do it right.  In fact, I know of a very famous Italian restaurant in NY that freezes their pasta which they make fresh everyday.  They cycle through new pasta every three days and they serve A LOT of pasta.  The chef dared me to tell the difference.  And he's right.  99.9% of people can't tell.

To freeze, bundle into small amounts (e.g. wrap around your hand), enough for single servings.  Put on a tray, with a little semolina flour or cornmeal dusted underneath (to prevent sticking).  Keep each bunch separate, they shouldn't touch.  Put into freezer.  Once frozen (few hours), transfer to a ziplock freezer bag.  It will keep for several months, but I'd eat it within one month.

To use, dump straight into boiling water.  Make sure you have a big pot of water at a full boil (because the frozen pasta will drop the temperature more than unfrozen).  Stir immediately.

This works very well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is safe to freeze.  You want to freeze in a quantity you can eat or in a way you can get it to a quantity you can eat in a single portion.  I often dry mine then freeze.

Comment: And if you dry it well, you don't even have to freeze it, although if you use a lot of egg (most dry pasta is just semolina flour and water) freezing might be a little safer.

Comment: @Doug - personally I always make egg dough for my pasta, which is why I prefer to freeze it.

Answer (score 1):

Freeze away! After making the noodles but before cooking let the noodle air dry on a drying rack for maybe 30 minutes, then put in zipper freezer bags in whatever serving size you want. When it is time to eat - pull from freezer, have boiling salted water ready to go and plop it into the pan for 3-5 minutes. It will cook a lot faster. No need to defrost. You can also make raviolis and then freeze them.  Works great for me, egg or egg-free.